# Adding own library to QT creator C project

Tags: c, qt-creator, header-files

How can I use my own C library in QT creator C project? After googling I met two ways to do that:

1. Creating a completely new library and copy/paste your own library codes into the new library in QT creator.
2. The second one is done by "Add Existing Files" where you need to just adjust path and libs.

But both of them give in my case "undefined reference to ...". 
I think and believe that it is because of linking problem. What is the solution for that? Any suggestions appreciated.

I could solve the same problem in Geany by altering "Set Build Command" from "gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" to "gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" "myHeader.c". Here myHeader.h is my own library.
I am coding completely on C.

Comment: Right click on the name of your project and select the option "Add Library", then "System Library" selecting the .so / .a / .dll / .lib according to your case.

Comment: A library is not a .c, a library often refers to at least one .so/.a and .h, the .c are unnecessary.

Comment: You really should read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and then [How to write shared libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Comment: @eyllanesc After selecting "System Library" does not show my header file when I browse. Should *.h files be there?

Comment: @user3622770 You have to select the .so or .a. Are you really sure that you have a library or just have a set of files?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have set of file including *.h and *.c. The file *.h contains all function definitions and *.c contains all source code of those functions. Now, how can I link these file to my ongoing QT creator project, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a library technically speaking, you only have a set of files, a simple solution is to create a .pri where those files are added and link the .pri to .pro:

```
├── your_project.pro
├── main.c
├── ...
├── ...
└── mylibrary
    ├── file1.h
    ├── file1.c
    ├── file2.h
    ├── file2.c
    └── mylibrary.pri
```

**mylibrary.pri**

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

SOURCES += \
    $$PWD/file1.c \
    $$PWD/file2.c

HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/file1.h \
    $$PWD/file2.h
```

**your_project.pro**

```
# ...

include(mylibrary/mylibrary.pri)
```

Comment: @user3622770 I recommend you to learn how to create libraries, the links that Basile Starynkevitch gave you tell you how to do it, since the disadvantage of my method is that many will have to compile the .c and .h and in a large project it can take hours, instead with the .so/.a + .h will not do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendation. I was not even aware of that.